# Extracting Certain Data from a Data Set Using R

Tags: r

I have difficulties in extracting certain line from a data. 
Let's say I use this command and I get a set of data, as below.

```
fpe <- read.table("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/effort.dat")

fpe

               setting effort change

Bolivia             46      0      1
Brazil              74      0     10
Chile               89     16     29
Colombia            77     16     25
CostaRica           84     21     29
Cuba                89     15     40
DominicanRep        68     14     21
Ecuador             70      6      0
ElSalvador          60     13     13
Guatemala           55      9      4
Haiti               35      3      0
Honduras            51      7      7
Jamaica             87     23     21
Mexico              83      4      9
Nicaragua           68      0      7
Panama              84     19     22
Paraguay            74      3      6
Peru                73      0      2
TrinidadTobago      84     15     29
Venezuela           91      7     11
```

Now, if i just want the reading of setting, effort and change for certain countries, say Bolivia, Cuba and Mexico, what type of coding should I use?

I'm very new to R and I really need help. Thanking in advance.

Comment: I think it  might be a good idea to read an introductory R site like Quick-R to get yourself started: http://www.statmethods.net/ In this case, your countries are actually a `rowname` instead of a proper column inside the `fpe` dataset.

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply. The website is helpful. But, may I know what do you mean by proper column? Do I need to do a data.frame in order to get a proper column?

Comment: @shuba - try this - `fpe$country <- rownames(fpe)` then try printing `fpe` again. Also read here: http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/dataframes.html the section called `Data Frame Indexing and Row Names`

Comment: I don't think that the question was the same as the supposed duplicate, nor was it clear from the answer how one would have selected rows based on rownames values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to select by rownames:

```
 fpe[ rownames(fpe) %in% c('Bolivia', 'Cuba', 'Mexico'), ]
```