# Subset a data frame for each factor level

Tags: r, subset

Given the dataset `red_wine_data` below, how can I create the list `l` which contains the following four subsetted data frames for all values in `unique(red_wine_data$condition)`? **I'm looking for a flexible and dynamic solution that produces a result similar to these hard-coded commands, but that will work for any similar data frame even if the factor levels change.**

```
l[["red_usa"]] <- subset(red_wine_data, red_wine_data$condition=="USA")
l[["red_france"]] <- subset(red_wine_data, red_wine_data$condition=="France")
l[["red_australia"]] <- subset(red_wine_data, red_wine_data$condition=="Australia")
l[["red_argentina"]] <- subset(red_wine_data, red_wine_data$condition=="Argentina")

red_wine_data <- structure(list(subject = 1:400, condition = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Argentina", 
"Australia", "France", "USA"), class = "factor"), Ratings = c(77L, 
82L, 75L, 92L, 83L, 75L, 84L, 86L, 85L, 79L, 92L, 84L, 77L, 65L, 
89L, 81L, 81L, 88L, 87L, 85L, 87L, 86L, 82L, 67L, 85L, 81L, 80L, 
71L, 78L, 84L, 91L, 80L, 84L, 81L, 71L, 78L, 78L, 81L, 89L, 86L, 
80L, 79L, 86L, 85L, 76L, 76L, 84L, 86L, 80L, 87L, 84L, 77L, 83L, 
73L, 91L, 95L, 78L, 74L, 85L, 80L, 98L, 81L, 86L, 81L, 76L, 82L, 
68L, 91L, 82L, 96L, 84L, 76L, 85L, 74L, 72L, 83L, 78L, 81L, 82L, 
77L, 77L, 80L, 89L, 70L, 85L, 83L, 88L, 79L, 84L, 83L, 77L, 89L, 
89L, 86L, 92L, 85L, 72L, 77L, 72L, 78L, 70L, 91L, 95L, 89L, 76L, 
87L, 75L, 86L, 73L, 85L, 73L, 79L, 82L, 73L, 80L, 84L, 93L, 91L, 
77L, 86L, 65L, 74L, 77L, 73L, 82L, 69L, 89L, 84L, 72L, 63L, 63L, 
73L, 79L, 82L, 80L, 73L, 79L, 74L, 88L, 76L, 72L, 79L, 76L, 75L, 
64L, 57L, 68L, 82L, 81L, 76L, 59L, 92L, 67L, 63L, 76L, 81L, 69L, 
73L, 86L, 75L, 74L, 70L, 76L, 66L, 69L, 68L, 77L, 69L, 92L, 78L, 
83L, 76L, 80L, 79L, 77L, 86L, 71L, 81L, 76L, 71L, 70L, 87L, 79L, 
71L, 70L, 91L, 74L, 67L, 76L, 61L, 83L, 66L, 67L, 86L, 70L, 73L, 
77L, 70L, 79L, 69L, 71L, 81L, 67L, 66L, 80L, 71L, 70L, 60L, 39L, 
65L, 64L, 75L, 77L, 58L, 73L, 63L, 89L, 69L, 89L, 69L, 86L, 72L, 
68L, 72L, 91L, 60L, 60L, 93L, 79L, 50L, 89L, 83L, 55L, 63L, 86L, 
77L, 81L, 64L, 71L, 77L, 76L, 65L, 75L, 69L, 79L, 50L, 65L, 75L, 
75L, 65L, 84L, 68L, 78L, 71L, 83L, 78L, 63L, 65L, 56L, 80L, 78L, 
73L, 52L, 60L, 69L, 60L, 67L, 90L, 76L, 54L, 56L, 83L, 81L, 67L, 
73L, 79L, 40L, 78L, 98L, 65L, 75L, 63L, 60L, 94L, 54L, 85L, 71L, 
62L, 79L, 39L, 80L, 89L, 66L, 65L, 57L, 80L, 76L, 72L, 65L, 71L, 
63L, 63L, 66L, 66L, 69L, 61L, 73L, 67L, 66L, 65L, 73L, 65L, 67L, 
66L, 76L, 63L, 67L, 54L, 71L, 63L, 76L, 68L, 66L, 72L, 64L, 80L, 
68L, 63L, 69L, 69L, 62L, 65L, 72L, 68L, 67L, 62L, 69L, 63L, 69L, 
67L, 63L, 57L, 63L, 69L, 76L, 66L, 62L, 60L, 62L, 64L, 76L, 64L, 
63L, 67L, 66L, 61L, 68L, 69L, 78L, 73L, 68L, 61L, 69L, 69L, 64L, 
63L, 66L, 75L, 70L, 75L, 68L, 57L, 63L, 65L, 69L, 66L, 74L, 71L, 
62L, 67L, 68L, 62L, 68L, 74L, 61L, 68L, 71L, 63L, 59L, 71L, 65L, 
63L, 62L, 71L, 65L, 66L, 64L, 71L, 60L, 69L)), .Names = c("subject", 
"condition", "Ratings"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", 
"281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", 
"290", "291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", 
"299", "300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", 
"308", "309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", 
"317", "318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", 
"326", "327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", 
"335", "336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", 
"344", "345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", 
"362", "363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", 
"371", "372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", 
"380", "381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", 
"389", "390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", 
"398", "399", "400"))
```

References:

- [how to extract a subset of a data frame based on a condition involving a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445590/how-to-extract-a-subset-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-condition-involving-a-field)
- [Extracting Certain Data from a Data Set Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329663/extracting-certain-data-from-a-data-set-using-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [R - find all unique values among subsets of a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873203/r-find-all-unique-values-among-subsets-of-a-data-frame)
- [How subset a data frame by a factor and repeat a plot for each subset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19146665/how-subset-a-data-frame-by-a-factor-and-repeat-a-plot-for-each-subset)
- https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/intro-to-statistics-with-r-introduction/chapter-two-histograms-and-distributions?ex=7 (original data)

Note that the example data comes from a Datacamp exercise, which I've already solved. This question is motivated by solving that exercise, but not identical.

Comment: Thanks @user20650, that's exactly what I needed. I posted it as an answer for completeness, but if you want to post the same answer maybe with any other interesting tips, then I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A single line of code will do:

```
l <- split(red_wine_data, red_wine_data$condition)
```